# Simple Question: What do I put in my method's parameters to input my arraylist?

Tags: java

I have a method here in my custom class that sorts my arraylist. The only problem is that i'm not sure of the syntax of inputting my arraylist into the method, errors just appear saying "illegal start of type". This seems like a very simple issues in which i am just lacking the knowledge of the syntax and can't seem to find anything on the internet that shows me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public ArrayList <Integer> selectionSort(<Integer> recordTimes){ //The selection sort algorithm

        for(int i=0;i<recordTimes.length-1;i++){  //Iterate through the list of numbers
            for(int j=i+1;j<recordTimes.length;j++){ 
                if(recordTimes[i]>recordTimes[j]){
                    int temp = recordTimes[i];
                    recordTimes[i] = recordTimes[j];
                    recordTimes[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return recordTimes;
    }
```

Error message: "illegal start of type"

Comment: Since you use `recordTimes.length`, `recordTimes` would have to be an `Integer[]`, which is an *array*, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: There is a `ArrayList` missing before `<Integer>`. It should be `... selectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> recordTimes) ...`

Comment: Guys, make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `recordTimes.length`, `recordTimes` would have to be an `Integer[]`, which is an *array*, not an `ArrayList`.

Either:

- Declare `Integer[] recordTimes` (and change the return type to `Integer[]` also);
- Declare it as `ArrayList<Integer> recordTimes`, and use `size()` instead of `length`, and `get` and `set` in the swap operation (although [`Collections.swap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,int,int)) is a more concise way to swap list elements).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution but i did not check if you implemented selection sort correctly.

```
int [] array = {2,4,5,6,4,7,9,4};

int [] sortedArray = selectionSort(array);


public int[] selectionSort(int [] recordTimes){ //The selection sort algorithm
    for(int i=0;i<recordTimes.length-1;i++){  //Iterate through the list of numbers
        for(int j=i+1;j<recordTimes.length;j++){ 
            if(recordTimes[i]>recordTimes[j]){
                int temp = recordTimes[i];
                recordTimes[i] = recordTimes[j];
                recordTimes[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return recordTimes;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the reply, I did not know arraylists were incompatible with methods of these types.

Comment: If it solved your problem then kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an ArrayList of integers to the method like

```
public ArrayList<Integer> selectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> recordTimes) {
  // rest of your code.
}
```